# Change font weight also change font-family Laravel--dompdf

Tags: laravel

If I change font weight it also change the font-family of it. How can I stop it

```
   body{
            font-family: 'sans-serif';
        }

  <body>
  <table style="width: 100%">
             <tr style="font-weight: 500">
                     <td style="font-size: 11px;">Shipper Account #</td>
                      <td style="font-size: 12px;">9585558</td>
              </tr>
             <tr style="font-weight: 500">
                   <td style="font-size: 11px;">Shipper Account #</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 12px;">9585558</td>
              </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
```

[image: Screenshot from 2021-04-19 16-54-25]

Comment: So you want to change the font-size without changing the font-family?

Comment: @MaartenDev Not the font size font-weight